# npm install git+ssh from private gitlab

Tags: git, npm

I have a private Gitlab. There I have a repo which I do git clone from this address: `[git@10.15.8.210:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git`

Until node 7.2.1 (npm v3.10.10) I could install like this:

```
$ npm install git+ssh://[git@10.15.8.210:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git --save
src@0.0.0 /home/pauloh/src/recsystem-web/src
└── robotRecSystem@1.1.0  (git+ssh://[git@10.15.8.210:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git#b589aa1d17cb44d5c17e5fd69929a7a8b64c9eba)
```

But since node 8.9.0 (npm v5.5.1) when I get an error with the same command:

```
$ npm install git+ssh://[git@10.15.8.210:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git --save
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://%5Bgit@10.15.8.210/:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.15.8.210/: Name or service not known
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pauloh/.npm/_logs/2018-07-11T13_00_48_101Z-debug.log
```

Reading the error, npm fails when calling the command git ls-remote.
It tryies this command:

```
/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://%5Bgit@10.15.8.210/:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git
```

It would work if I change this command to:

```
/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t [git@10.15.8.210:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git
```

So, I think the problems are:

- my url string `[git@10.15.8.210:8888]:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git` is not a normal url, since it is not a `protocol://user@hostname:port/path`
- npm is not parsing correctly my url string.
- npm is changing the character `[` to `%5B` and it is not working
- npm is prefixing the protocol `ssh://` and it is not working

How could I change my url string to npm parse it correctly?

Comment: Why does the URL have square brackets?

Comment: I don't know. That's how Gitlab gives me the url to ssh connection and git recognizes it. I do git clone with this address.

Comment: The npm adressing seems to have changed, try git+ssh://git@10.15.8.210:8888:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git and see yourself

Comment: Actually the last point is correct, with git+ssh you are telling npm that git should be called for cloning and that ssh protocol should be used inside git.

Comment: Perhaps remove the square brackets from the URL?

Comment: without brackets it freezes in this output: [..................] /  rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 61f2f738971f6af5

Comment: @PauloHenrique the "rollbackFailedOptional", however, seems to be the issue with npm: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17246

Answer (score 1):

The brackets in `npm install` documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

```
<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]
```

mean only that this part may not be used, not that you have to include the brackets...

Therefore, `git+ssh://git@10.15.8.210:8888:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git` seems to be what you are looking for.

OR

You can use the definition of `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` variable to set the port beforehand to eliminate possible problems with the colons:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -p 8888' git+ssh://git@10.15.8.210:recsystem/robotRecSystem.git
```

OR even better

You may define the port in the `.ssh/config` as described in: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client

Comment: How would I use this GIT_SSH_COMMAND with npm install or inside package.json?

Comment: Well, the first option (:8888 after <host>) should work just fine, what you are experiencing with the "rollbackFailedOptional" seems to be an unrelated issue